# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n \int_0^1 \frac{\,dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/2}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}\mathrm{d}x=0
$$

Is my answer correct?
But I am not sure of method by which I have done.

Comment: What method did you use to get 0?

Comment: ... and I'm getting $\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: try substitution $x=\tan\theta$

Answer (score 12):

No. With the change of variable $ t = \sqrt{n} x $ you get $$ \sqrt{n} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} \, dx = \int_0^\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n} \, dt = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n} \chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(t) \, dt. $$Observe that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n \chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(t) = e^{t^2}$$pointwise everywhere, say for $t>0$; also the sequence $ n \mapsto (1 + t^2 /n)^n$ is increasing for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ which implies that $$\frac{1}{1+t^2} \ge \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n} \ge \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n} \chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(t) $$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, since $1/(1+t^2) \in L^1([0,+\infty))$, we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{t^2}{n} \right)^n} \chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(t) \, dt = \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}. $$

Comment: If we take $x_0 \in (0,1)$ we have that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(1+x_0^2)^n} \to 0$

Comment: This question came in a test for high schoolers yesterday (I gave it too) and your approach is quite out of our reach. The question was actually simpler as it also stated that the limit existed, ie , the integral tends to $\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ where c is positive. Maybe we could use this and dumber down the solution a bit?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: no matter how much you "*dumb it down*", you'll still need to get a $\sqrt{\pi}$ *out of something*.

Comment: (+1) In regards of the Necky

Answer (score 12):

Nope, the limit cannot be zero. In a right neighbourhood of the origin $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\approx e^{-x^2}$, and for large values of $n$ we have that $\int_{0}^{1}e^{-nx^2}\,dx$ is horribly close to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nx^2}\,dx$, which scales like $\frac{K}{\sqrt{n}}$ for a positive constant $K$. This actually is the main idea of the Laplace/Hayman methods. In our case

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\stackrel{x\mapsto\tan\theta}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos^{2n-2}(\theta)\,d\theta $$
is at most $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}$ apart from
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-2}(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^{n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}=\frac{\pi n}{(2n-1)4^n}\binom{2n}{n}, $$
and since $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ (by Wallis product or similar elementary manipulations) we have
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}.$$

Comment: Can the solution be simpler if we were provided that the limit exists and is positive? It was provided so in the actual question.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: what do you mean by *simpler*? Both answers now prove that the limit is precisely $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Simpler in the sense that you can assume the limit exists. This question came in a test today for high schoolers (which I gave) with this additional info that the OP probably forgot to add.

Comment: The fact that the limit is positive is fairly obvious, but in order to compute it you *need* to know the value of the Gaussian integral or, equivalently, the value of $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}n\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]^2,$$ i.e. Wallis' product or some form of the central limit theorem.

Comment: Sorry . Your  solution is actually within my grasp. I never actually read the complete solution because the first few lines did not make sense to me.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please disregard the previous comment.  I understand what you meant.

Answer (score 7):

Let 
\begin{align*}
I_n&=\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}=\left.\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n}\right|_{x=0}^\infty+\int_0^\infty\frac{2nx^2\,dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\\
&=2n\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}-2n\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}=2nI_n-2nI_{n+1}
\end{align*}
So we get
\begin{align*}I_{n+1}&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_n=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}I_{n-1}=\cdots\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}I_1=4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac \pi 2
\end{align*}
By Stirling's formula,
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}=I_{n+1}+O(\tfrac 1 n)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\cdot\frac\pi 2=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt n}$$
Thus the original limit equals
$$\sqrt n\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2\sqrt{n-1}}\to\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}=0.8862\ldots$$

Comment: Did you mean for the first few integrals to be from $0$ to $1$ instead of $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 They were meant to be $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: Oh nvm. I see how your solution works now. $\int_{1}^{\infty}(1+x^2)^{-(n+1)}\,dx \le \int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-(2n+2)}\,dx = O(1/n)$, which is how you got $\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2)^{-(n+1)}\,dx = I_{n+1}+O(1/n)$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
This can be evaluated by means of
[Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{n}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{1/2}\int_{0}^{1}
\exp\pars{-n\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-nx^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\bbx{\root{\pi} \over 2} \approx 0.8862 \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

If you are fine with using the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values) (specifically $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}$) and the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (DCT), then there is another way of finding your limit:

- Having in mind to get an $e$-function in the denominator, using the substitution $x^2=\frac{u}{n}$ you get
  $$I_n = \sqrt{n}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} dx = \frac 12 \int_0^{\color{blue}{n}}\frac{du}{\sqrt u\left(1+\frac un\right)^n}$$
- Now, in order to apply the DCT, we need to bound the integrand properly:

$$I_n = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\color{blue}{1}}\frac{du}{\sqrt u\left(1+\frac un\right)^n} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{n}}\frac{du}{\sqrt u\left(1+\frac un\right)^n}$$ 
$$ <  \frac 12 \int_0^{\color{blue}{1}}\frac{du}{\sqrt u} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{n}}\frac{du}{\sqrt u(1+u)}$$
$$< 1 + \int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{\infty}}\frac{du}{u^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 2$$

So, we are allowed to apply the DCT and get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}e^u}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}u^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-u}\;du$$ $$= \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}$$

Comment: I like your approach, simple and nice :)

Comment: @VukStojiljkovic : Thank you for your appreciation. :-)

Answer (score -3):

$$I(n)=\sqrt{n}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
and since $$(1+x^2)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{{n+k-1}\choose k}(-1)^kx^{2k}$$
$$I(n)=\sqrt{n}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty{{n+k-1}\choose k}(-1)^kx^{2k}dx=\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{{n+k-1}\choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
and we know that:
$${{n+k-1}\choose k}=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$$
and as $n\to\infty$ this will $\to1$
so we are left with:
$$I(n)\approx\sqrt{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$
now take the limit

Comment: All the answers below claim that the limit is $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$. From your analysis, it follows that $I(n)\to +\infty$. So who is right?

Comment: a simple test on a calculator gave me that for $n=10,000,000$ you get $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ to 9 decimal places so my money's on this answer being wrong.

Comment: Note that for $n,k\geq 1$, $$
\frac{{(n + k - 1)!}}{{k!(n - 1)!}}\geq \frac{{n^k }}{{k!}},
$$ showing that this binomail tends to $+\infty$ rather than $0$ when $n\to +\infty$.