# How to find the limit of:

Tags: integration, limits

if the limit $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt n \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx$$exists and is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ then  prove that $\frac{1}{2} < L < 2 $ .

Comment: Perhaps you could show us your current thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Is $n$ a real variable?

Comment: Long time duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984468/finding-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-n-int-01-frac-dx1x2n, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998545/l-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-int-01-dfracdx1x2n.

Answer (score 0):

Using $(1+x^2)^n>1+nx^2$ for $x\geq 0$

So $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}<\frac{1}{1+nx^2}$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}\int^{1}_{0}<\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{1+nx^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}<2.$$

So we get $$\frac{1}{2}<L<2.$$

Comment: the limit L is certainly less than 2 (as DXT has proved above) but who to prove that it is greater than 0.5